# Docker repo isn't adding correctly on Linux Mint 20.3 (Una)

Tags: linux-mint, docker

I'm new to Linux and as such I'm sure that I'm missing something simple. I'm following instructions via [Docker Engine Install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository)

After running

> $ echo 
> "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu 
> $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

and then running

> $ sudo apt-get update

I'm getting this back

> Ign:1 http#://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease
> Hit:2 http#://packages.linuxmint.com una Release
> Hit:3 https#://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
> Ign:5 https#://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu una InRelease
> Hit:6 http#://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
> Hit:7 https#://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease
> Err:8 https#://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu una Release
> 404  Not Found [IP: 108.156.91.7 443]
> Hit:9 http#://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:10 http#://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Get:11 http#://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
> Get:12 http#://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
> Get:13 http#://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
> Reading package lists... Done
> E: The repository 'https#://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu una Release' does not have a Release file.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Fairly sure that I could just download the package, but then I'd have to manually update.
So this is essentially where I'm stuck.

My info:

> NAME="Linux Mint"
> VERSION="20.3 (Una)"
> ID=linuxmint
> ID_LIKE=ubuntu
> PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 20.3"
> VERSION_ID="20.3"

I added # to links to break them. I don't have enough clout to post that many links to a question.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can hard code your goal ubuntu version in this comand, just replace $(lsb_release -cs) with my goal ubuntu version "focal" (20.04) but i have 20.03.

$ echo
"deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
focal stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

Worked for me. GL!